# Поменять иконку(mdi) при клике Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue3

У меня есть таблица и в ней иконки вот одна из них:

```
      <template v-slot:item.actionRun="{ item }">
       <v-icon @click="() => {showAlertAndToggleAction(item)}">
          {{ item.isRunning ? 'mdi-play' : 'mdi-stop' }}
       </v-icon>
     </template>
```

Есть js код который при клике на иконку должен её менять и выводить alert:

```
   toggleAction(item) {
  this.$set(item, 'isRunning', !item.isRunning);
  this.$forceUpdate();
  alert('второй' + item.isRunning);
  console.log('Toggling action for item', item.id);},
```

и его продолжение

```
showAlertAndToggleAction(item) {
  alert("первый"+ item.isRunning);
  this.toggleAction(item);
  alert('второй'+ item.isRunning);
},
```

При клике, выводится alert, но иконка не меняется, почему так и как это можно исправить?

Comment: $set, вроде бы, из Vue3 убрали. Поэтому можно просто ```item.isRunning = !item.isRunning;```. А ```item.isRunning``` - реактивная переменная?

Comment: удали item из массива и добавь измененный. тригернется key и оно перерисуется на месте